# How to use the sum the value of 2 totals in different table (Reporting Services)?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

In report design, I have 2 tables (Current and Proposed) the structure like this:

Current

```
Parameter | Value | Rate | Total

Value ...
```

Proposed

```
Parameter | Value | Rate | Total

Value ...
```

Each bottom of the table (Table Footer), I have something called: "Total: " which is a sum of Total field. I called these textboxes are txtbxCurrent and txtbxProposed and the format is in currency already.

This thing is running well.

But now I need to get a total of these txtbxCurrent  and txtbxProposed. How do I do this? Can I take the value of this or not?

BTW .. I am using Ms SQL Server 2005 (ReportViewer - client)

Also here my SINGLE dataset looks like:

```
RecID | ReportView | Type | Parameter | Value | Rate | Total
1, 'Detail', CURRENT, 'Param1', 100, 0.1, 10
1, 'Detail', CURRENT, 'Param2', 200, 0.2, 10
1, 'Detail', PROPOSED, 'Param1', 100, 0.2, 20
1, 'Detail', PROPOSED, 'Param2', 200, 0.2, 20
```

The only I can think of is that I could append for another ReportView such as 'Ttl' but I am just wondering I could do from the current dataset.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013763/reporting-services-two-tables-one-sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you create a new table that only has the totals for the third table?

ex:

Table 1
Table 2
Table 3 (only has total of Table 1 + Table 2)

You might be able to use parameters to store the totals to add as well, but a 3rd table would be pretty easy to create.

Comment: That what I am think of actually. But I will append the current data set. Cause we have 'ReportView' field already. But I am trying other way if it's easy.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use `sum` function? you can use from `sum` function for each dataset and add these values in a new textbox.

**EDIT :**

if txtbxCurrent = `Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "CurrentDS")` and txtbxProposed = `Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "ProposedDS")`

then you can use this :

```
Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "CurrentDS") + Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "ProposedDS")
```

Comment: That what I did to get the total of each table. But I cound't work out I want to sum based on each view (current VS proposed) on different area if you know what I mean (like outside these 2 tables)

Comment: Also the data is coming from a single DATASET but we have a field to differentiate this.

Comment: you can use a parameter for specifying your purpose.

Comment: I got the following error: The Value expression for the textbox ‘textbox17’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a data set.

Comment: do you have 2 dataset or more?

Comment: If you have 2 dataset or more you must don't have any problem. I use this way in my reports.

Comment: @masoud ramezani: I only have 1 dataset.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a single dataset for both tables, how are you restricting each of them to current and proposed values respectively?

If you have a table-level filter on each table, the simplest approach might be to add a third table with no table-level filter, with a table footer row only, containing just

```
Sum(Fields!Total.Value)
```

Alternatively, it might be more efficient to rewrite the report to use a single table, grouped by ReportView, with footers containing sums of total at both group footer and table footer level.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate the total rows count from two or more different tables use this expression:
=Sum(1, "DataSet1") + Sum(1, "DataSet2")
By using 1 you're just summing 1-s instead of actual field values, which gives you count of rows.